# Adjust volume sound

Tags: sound, speakers

How do I adjust the volume of online videos I am watching? I've cranked my speakers up. I've selected the increased volume button on screen. I want to boost my sound. How do I do so, please?

Comment: Would you mind running `dpkg -l | grep '*pulse'` to see if you have PulseAudio or ALSA? Once we know, then we can dive into the appropriate version and dial it up there. If all else fails, you can add an in-line booster like https://www.google.com/search?q=Upbeat+Audio+T613BNC+Clear+BOOSTEROO&oq=Upbeat+Audio+T613BNC+Clear+BOOSTEROO&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 2):

In <kbd>Sound Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Applications</kbd>, make sure it is turned up:
[image]

also, try running `alsamixer` in terminal, and turning the PCM and other outputs up:

[image]